# Applescript: list dev nodes of mounted and not mounted disks

Tags: applescript, disk

Is it possible to get a list of dev nodes for disks using applescript? I found the system events application but cannot find the /dev entries there (like "/dev/disk1s1 on /"). I need something like 'mount' command but for the applescript.

Comment: How about `set foo to do shell script "mount"` or `tell application "System Events" to get properties of every disk` ?

Comment: Sure, but I'd rather like to use the internal dictionaries. It's my second script, so I don't have a much ideas how to use these dictionaries, hope, this ecample could help

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed "tell application "System Events" to get properties of every disk" Please show me an example

Comment: What explicitly and specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: to list all dev nodes and their mount points, if there's any. I'd like to understand how it all works and I found this useful. want to make mount/umount script then, but now I'd like to understand how it works

Comment: Re: "to list all dev nodes and their mount points, if there's any." the _shell_ `mount` command already does this and if you're looking for output that contains, e.g. "/dev/disk1s1 on /" then you'll need to parse the output of e.g `foo` in `set foo to do shell script "mount"` That said, sorry but I'm not totally sure what you really want and will have to let others help.

Comment: I'd like to do that using applescript and without using shell. It's clear thatI can achieve it with the shell but I wonder, is there a way to do that using applescript only? I supposed "system events" or "disk utility" has this data but cannot find it.

Comment: Disk Utility.app does not have an AppleScript Dictionary and its `has scripting terminology` is `false` although you might be able to use some form of UI Scripting, although I probably wouldn't. You certainly can try `tell application "System Events" to get properties of every disk` an look at its output so you can see what properties and their values are. FWIW IMO Trying to do things using only so called pure AppleScript is BS! The `do shell script` AppleScript command is there for good reasons, as not all information is retrievable without resorting to it and various shell commands at times!

Comment: I also did both before I asked here, and found nothing in the "System events" and also found that disk utility does not have a dictionary. "System events" has also the "disk items" which is empty (at least I cannot get any values from it). Sure, I already did it with the shell script (pure script, not a call from applescript) but it's my second applescript program and I started to try this applescript just to move this shell script functionality to the more native applescript )) That's why I'd like to find the "native" solution )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System Events` doesn't provide information about connected but unmounted disks.

You need to use the shell. To get the dev node use

```
set diskName to "MyVolume"
set devNode to do shell script "diskutil list | awk '/ " & diskName & " / {print $NF}'"
```

To mount a volume by name use

```
set diskName to "MyVolume"
do shell script "diskutil mount `diskutil list | awk '/ " & diskName & " / {print $NF}'`"
```

Comment: It’s clear that it’s possible to use shell to achieve that. Sad, that there’s no dictionary though